# split a list into two consisting of desired elements using python

Tags: python

I have a list as shown below :

```
[[[77.56913757324219, 12.975883483886719], [77.5671615600586, 12.976168632507324], [77.5680160522461, 12.980805397033691], [77.56996154785156, 12.980448722839355], [77.56913757324219, 12.975883483886719]]]
```

How can i split this into two lists such that one list contains all the elements in odd places and the other consists of elements at even places. The output I am expecting to get is:

```
list1 = [[[77.56913757324219, 12.975883483886719],[77.5680160522461, 12.980805397033691],[77.56913757324219, 12.975883483886719]]]
```

and

```
list2 = [[[77.5671615600586, 12.976168632507324],[77.56996154785156, 12.980448722839355]]]
```

I looking for a solution using python.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
biglist = [[
    [77.56913757324219, 12.975883483886719], [77.5671615600586, 12.976168632507324], 
    [77.5680160522461, 12.980805397033691], [77.56996154785156, 12.980448722839355], 
    [77.56913757324219, 12.975883483886719]
]]

list1 = [ biglist[0][::2] ]
list2 = [ biglist[0][1::2] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
list1 = list[::2]
```

AND

```
list2 = list[1::2]
```

These both use list splicing and the third specified parameter, `[::2]` specifies a step value of 2

#### Examples

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

>>> print a[::2]
[1,3,5,7]

>>> print a[1::2]
[2,4,6]
```

I know that in your example, the list is nested within other lists but I'll let you figure that out. Hope that helps.

Comment: The list in the question seems to be 'wrapped' by another list. So it should be `[list[::2]]` and `[list[1::2]]`.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik. You're right, I can add that. But please see my edit. My answer is simply a demonstration of how it can be achieved and not an actual answer.